# Do all error objects in Javascript have the same structure?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, error-handling

I'm implementing error outputting modal in React web app and therefore instead of just using `.catch((e) => console.log(e)` I'm planning to pass the error details into a separate component and display 3 parts of this error object: name, message, stack, in separate fields of this component.

I know that standard Error type object has all of those properties, however, I was wondering whether there are some exceptions and some error could be returned without all of these fields?

Comment: since you can `throw justAboutAnythingHere` then no, there is no guarantee that `e` will even be an `Error`, or derived from an `Error`, or even what properties `e` will contain ... it can even be a primitive ... `throw "hello world"` for example

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error - Looks like there are some other non-standard properties you could check for. (Even 'stack' is apparently non-standard.)

Comment: also, since this looks like a Promise .catch, you can reject with anything at all, so, no guarantee `e` will be an `Error`

Comment: What if I wrap the value that catch is return in new Error as here? - 
.catch(e => {
   const error = new Error(e);
    setError(error);
});

setError in this case is the action creator in redux that leads to update of global state with error

Comment: `new Error(e)` does not make sense because the constructor for an Error object accepts a string, not an object as the first argument.  If you want to make sure the error you're propagating is an Error object, then you can first check to see `if (e instanceof Error)` and then make your own Error object if not.  Ideally, you would know what the code you call can reject with (e.g. whether something other than an Error object is possible).